# access the prev state with useDispatch

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, react-redux, redux-toolkit

i am tryin to set up refreshToken hook and then to set up the userSlice with it but when i dispatch the token all other properties are removed from initalState how can when dispatching to return the prev state and update the new token?

```
import axios from "axios";
import { AppDispatch } from "../store";
import { useDispatch } from "react-redux";
import { setAuth } from "../features/auth/authSlice";

const useRefreshToken = () => {
  const dispatch:AppDispatch = useDispatch()
  const refresh = async () => {
    const response = await axios.get("http://localhost:80/auth/refresh", {
      withCredentials: true,
    });
    console.log(response);
    
    dispatch(setAuth({...response.data}));
    return response.data.accessToken
  };
  return refresh
};

export default useRefreshToken;
```

Comment: What does your `setAuth` do?

Comment: Your issue is when you call `setAuth`, previous properties of state `auth` is overwritten by `response.data`? You want to keep the old state and only overwrite the keys in `response.data`?

Comment: yes c0m1t i want to overwrite only the expired access token